# Why control keyboard doesn't work? Right and left mouse

Tags: python, keyboard, pygame, controls, mouse

The file alien_invasion.py is the main file of the app. Why control mouse doesn't work? How make control keyboard to this example and control ship with left and right site?

## file in which is control mouse/keyboard

file: game_functions.py

```
import sys
import pygame

def check_events(ship):


    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                ship.moving_right = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                 ship.moving_left = True

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP :
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                ship.moving_right = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                ship.moving_left = False
```

## settings for ship

file: ship.py

```
import pygame

class Ship():
    def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen):
        self.screen = screen
        self.ai_settings = ai_settings

        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/ship.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

        self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
        self.rect.bottom = self.screen_rect.bottom

        self.moving_right = False
        self.moving_left = False

        self.center = float(self.rect.centerx)


    def blitme(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

    def update(self):


        if self.moving_right and self.rect.right < self.screen_rect.right:
            self.center += self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor
        if self.moving_left and self.rect.left > 0:
            self.center -= self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor

        self.rect.centerx = self.center
```

## the main file which run app

file: alien_invasion.py

```
import sys
import pygame
from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship
import game_functions as gf

def run_game():
    pygame.init()
    pygame.display.set_caption("Inwazja obcych")
    ai_settings = Settings()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((ai_settings.screen_width, ai_settings.screen_height))
    ship = Ship(ai_settings, screen)
    gf.update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship)
    gf.check_events(ship)
    ship.update()

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()

        screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)
        ship.blitme()
        pygame.display.flip()

run_game()
```

Comment: Why don't you just use the WASD keys instead. Just use `K_w` rather than `K_RIGHT`. Just an inquiry if you want to try that. That might work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you call the `check_events` function only once; then you enter the `while True:` loop and never check for keyboard events again.

What would really help you is learning debugging techniques. Either try using a debugger or use simple `print` statements to be able to tell what your program is doing.